# Wiktionary import doesn't look anything like the official site

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, wiktionary

[This is the official version](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sirocco). This is what my imported copy looks like:

[image: My imported copy]

The steps I used were as follows:

1. Used mwdumper (Java app) to generate a SQL dump of enwiktionary-DATE_HERE-pages-meta-current
2. Imported that into a fresh installation of mediawiki.
3. Ran `php maintenance/refreshLinks.php`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `{{#invoke}}` is used by [the Scribunto extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto). You have to install that (and possibly other extensions that are used by Wiktionary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's a fresh installation, you will need to install [all the extensions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special%3aVersion#mw-version-ext) that are installed in Wiktionary as well to get the same look; you're especially looking for the parser hooks like `ParserFunctions` and `Scribunto`.